# Relative path problem while making HTML. The image is not shown

Tags: html, css

The follows is the code

```
<html>
<h1 style="min-height: 5vh;background-size:cover;color:rgba(79.0,243.0,0.0,1);justify-content: center;display: flex;font-size: 5rem;align-items: center;background-image: url('User Content\abc.svg');">dasfgasdfgadfsg</h1><h1 style="min-height: 100vh;background-size:cover;color:rgba(78.0,224.0,140.0,1);justify-content: center;display: flex;font-size: 5rem;align-items: center;background-image: **url('Images\Builder Section\Heros\Plain and Simple.jpg')**;">Sample
</h1>
</html>
```

Can i get to know how to resolve it?
for reference: buildeer.tk # Site for seeing the code

Answer (score 1):

**Urls always use forward slashes: `/`, never backslashes: `\`**

Looks to me you should be using `/` instead of `\` as the separator within the `url(...)`, also, avoid using spaces within your directories names (spaces are not valid in a URI: they need to be encoded to `%20`), and do not forget to remove those `**` within your css surrounding the last `url(...)`

Also, unrelated, you're using two `h1`, which is non-semantic, there should only be one level 1 heading within your doc

Answer (score -1):

Also if you have spaces in directory names always use %20 in place of it so the url knows that the space is part of the name and isn't a seperation

Comment: Spaces are not valid in a URI. They need to be encoded to %20 - using a backslash isn't the way to do it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856345/1358317