# HTML / CSS How to add image icon to input type="button"?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the below CSS, but it puts an image in the center of the button. Any way to left or right align an icon using `<input type="button">`, so that the text and the image fit and align nicely?

```
background: url('/common/assets/images/icons/16x16/add.png');
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

If you absolutely must use `input`, try this:

```
background-image: url(...);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: <left|right>;
padding-<left|right>: <width of image>px;
```

It's usually a little easier to use a `button` with an `img` inside:

```
<button type="submit"><img> Text</button>
```

However the browser implementations of `button` for submitting are inconsistent, as well as the fact that all button values are sent when `button` is used - which kills the "what button clicked" detection in a multi-submit form.

Comment: don't have to, but I here button tag is buggy in ie 6 or behaves differently in some browsers?

Comment: As far as I've experienced, `button` (with type `submit`) works identically to `input` with the exception of allowing elements inside (rather than just styles applied to it).

Comment: The 'buggy' part of IE's `<button>` implementation comes from the fact that 1) on a POST / GET, it submits the 'values' for every button, and not just the one clicked, and 2) Instead of sending the actual `value` attribute, IE likes to send the contents (inner HTML) of the button. These facts make the `<button>` tag unreliable if the action taken depends on the button a user clicked.

Comment: Great point, Duroth. Yes, that's certainly a kicker for things like an edit post form that has "Preview" and "Submit", etc.

Comment: You can use `<button>` and `<input type=button>` interchangeably. If you don't want <button> submitting in I.E., set its type like so: `<button type="button">Text</button>`

Answer (score 77):

This should do do what you want, assuming your button image is 16 by 16 pixels.

```
<input type="button" value="Add a new row" class="button-add" />
```

```
input.button-add {
    background-image: url(/images/buttons/add.png); /* 16px x 16px */
    background-color: transparent; /* make the button transparent */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  /* make the background image appear only once */
    background-position: 0px 0px;  /* equivalent to 'top left' */
    border: none;           /* assuming we don't want any borders */
    cursor: pointer;        /* make the cursor like hovering over an <a> element */
    height: 16px;           /* make this the size of your image */
    padding-left: 16px;     /* make text start to the right of the image */
    vertical-align: middle; /* align the text vertically centered */
}
```

Example button:

### [image: example button]

**Update**

If you happen to use Less, this mixin might come in handy.

```
.icon-button(@icon-url, @icon-size: 16px, @icon-inset: 10px, @border-color: #000, @background-color: transparent) {
    height: @icon-size * 2;
    padding-left: @icon-size + @icon-inset * 2;
    padding-right: @icon-inset;
    border: 1px solid @border-color;
    background: @background-color url(@icon-url) no-repeat @icon-inset center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input.button-add {
    .icon-button("http://placehold.it/16x16", @background-color: #ff9900);
}
```

The above compiles into

```
input.button-add {
  height: 32px;
  padding-left: 36px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #ff9900 url("http://placehold.it/16x16") no-repeat 10px center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tk68M/)

Comment: don't you need quotes in the argument of the url() method?

Comment: No, we don't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/css-url-are-quotes-needed

Answer (score 14):

```html
<button type="submit" style="background-color:transparent; border-color:transparent;"> 
  <img src="images/button/signin.png" height="35"/>
</button>
<button type="reset" style="background-color:transparent; border-color:transparent;"> 
  <img src="images/button/reset.png" height="35"/>
</button>
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using spritesheets this becomes impossible and the element must be wrapped.

```
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.input, .btn:after{
    color: #fff;
}
.btn:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '@';
    right: 0;
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1em;
}
.input{
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AJNnZ/

Answer (score 2):

you can try insert image inside button
http://jsfiddle.net/s5GVh/1415/

```
<button type="submit"><img src='https://aca5.accela.com/bcc/app_themesDefault/assets/gsearch_disabled.png'/></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is do this:

### Use a button type

```
 <button type="submit" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.0); border:none;" id="resultButton" onclick="showResults();"><img src="images/search.png" /></button>
```

I used background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.0); So that the original background color of a button goes away. The same with the border:none; it will take the original border away.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this trick!

1st) do this:

```
<label for="img">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="img" value="img-btn">
   <img src="yourimage.jpg" id="img">
</label>
```

2nd) style it!

```
<style type="text/css">
   img:hover {
       cursor: pointer;
   }
   input[type=submit] {
       display: none;
   }
</style>
```

It is not clean but it will do the job!

Answer (score 1):

Simply add icon in button element here is the example

```
   <button class="social-signup facebook"> 
     <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>  
      Sign up with Facebook</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the minimal style needed, fitting the image to the default button size:

```html
<input type="button" value=" " style="background-image: url(http://www.geppoz.eu/geppoz.png);background-size:100% 100%;">
```

the "spaced" value is needed to keep baseline alignment, just in case you need it...

Answer (score 0):

sshow's answer did it for me, too:

**navigation.css**:

```
[...]

.buttonConfiguration {
    width: 40px;
    background-color: red; /* transparent; */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: corbel;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 1px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;

    background-image: url('../images/icons5/gear_16.png');
    background-position: center; /* 0px 0px; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

[...]
```

**frameMenu.php**:

```
[... PHP, Javascript and HTML code ...]

<!-- <li><a target="frameBody" href="admin/conf/confFunctions.php"><input type="button" class="buttonSuperAdmin" value="<?= $oLanguage->getExpression('confSettings', 'title', 'C e n t e r s') ?>"></a> -->
<li><a target="frameBody" href="admin/conf/confFunctions.php"><input type="button" class="buttonConfiguration" value=""></a>
<ul>
<li><a target="frameBody" href="admin/conf/getglobals.php "><input type="button" class="buttonSuperAdminSub" value="<?= $oLanguage->getExpression('centerSettings', 'confAdmin1', 'GetGlobals') ?>"></a></li>
<li><a target="frameBody" href="admin/conf/getcwd.php "><input type="button" class="buttonSuperAdminSub" value="<?= $oLanguage->getExpression('confSettings', 'centerAdmin2', 'GetCWD') ?>"></a></li>
</ul>
</li>

[...]
```

I have tested this successfully under the lastest versions of Firefox and Chrome (as of February 9th, 2019).

Answer (score 0):

[image: What it looks like]

This works well for me, and I'm handling hover and click CSS as well (by changing background color):

HTML (here showing 2 images, image1 on top of image2):

```
<button class="iconButton" style="background-image: url('image1.png'), url('image2.png')"
  onclick="alert('clicked');"></button>
```

CSS (my images are 32px X 32px, so I gave them 4px for padding and a 5px border rounding):

```
.iconButton {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.iconButton:hover {
    background-color: #303030;
}

.iconButton:active {
    background-color: #606060;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<img src="http://www.pic4ever.com/images/2mpe5id.gif">
            <button class="btn btn-<?php echo $settings["button_background"]; ?>" type="submit"><?php echo $settings["submit_button_text"]; ?></button>
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Needs a ">" to close the img tag.

Comment: Why are you using PHP?