# HTML 4 <button> in JSF 2.1

Tags: java, html, jsf, jsf-2, html4

I would like to use the commands:

The JSF `<h:commandButton>` generates an `<input...>` but I would like that instead of generating the `<input>` I would like that this generate a HTML 4 standard`<button>`.

Comment: What commands would you like to use?

Comment: Also, JSF is kind of terrible when it comes to finely controlling HTML output. I'd strongly suggest against using it if your graphical design needs go too far beyond "pick a RichFaces theme". I think that in this case you can just put a regular HTML `<button type="button">` inside a `<h:commandLink>` though.

Comment: JSF by default doesn't generate `<button>` HTML tag. It would be necessary to add why would you need it? If you want a button with an image, then see [How to create a button in JSF page with custom label](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11802031/1065197)

Comment: I`m using bootstrap and my css need to be an <output> to show icons on the botton. I wouldn't like to customize my css to suport it. I think it would be so much better if the JSF generates it.

Comment: [PrimeFaces has since recently a Bootstrap theme](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2139).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into the Primefaces `p:commandButton`.  This will render to a `<button>` tag on the client.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandButton.jsf

Answer (score 11):

Closest what you can get with standard JSF component set is `<input type="button">` which is generated by [`<h:button>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/button.html).

```html
<h:button value="Button" />
```

which generates

```html
<input id="j_id_1" name="j_id_1" type="button" value="Button" onclick="window.location.href = '/context/currentpage.xhtml'" />
```

If you really insist in using `<button>` for some unclear reason, then you have the following options:

- Just use plain HTML.
- Create a custom component and/or renderer.
- Grab a 3rd party component library. E.g. [PrimeFaces' `<p:button>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button.jsf) generates a `<button>`.

Comment: I was converting a CSS + HTML site into a JSF site. Changing CSS is not practical in the setting. If an input is generated instead of a button, the existing CSS does not style the generated input component. Adding a PrimeFaces button brings unwanted styling. I had no knowledge in creating custom components.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JSF 2.2, you can just use the `<button>` tag with jsf namespace mixed. The secret here is the attribute `process` from `jsf` namespace, that post the form data, and the `action` attribute.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
    jsf:action="#{profileController.updateProfile}"
    jsf:process="@form">
        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            #{bundle['button.store']}
</button>
```

In JSF 2.2 you can use any HTML tag mixing with JSF tags.

Comment: This saved me. Thank you so much. I was converting an HTML + CSS based site to JSF. Inserting a PrimeFaces button bought unnecessary stylings. Any other JSF component like command button or command link generated input in Html resulting in unexpected styling. As I am not the one responsible for CSS editing, modifying CSS was difficult. That is the value of your answer came very handy for me.

Answer (score -2):

It works for me by replacing `<button>` with `<h:commandLink>`, example:
Replace

```
<button class="RUIFW-btn-primary pull-right" 
        type="submit" 
        name="action" 
        value="Find" 
        onClick="return submitPage(this);">
     <span class="icon-search"></span>Find
</button>
```

with

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="RUIFW-btn-primary pull-right" 
title="#{msg['view.button.Find']}"
action="#{anotherAccountController.doFind}"
onclick="return submitPage(this.form)">
<span class="icon-search"></span>#{msg['view.button.Find']}
</h:commandLink>
```