# How to render a HTML button element in JSF 2.2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I really need to render a `<button>` element under JSF 2.2 and I wouldn't like to use third party libraries--such PrimeFaces--just for this.

Once Mojarra's `<h:commandButton>` only renders `<input>` elements, is there any native/elegant solution to fulfil that requirement?

So far I've discovered [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773907/html-4-button-in-jsf-2-1) here on SO but for JSF 2.1, and 2.2 might have received some update on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<button>` tag with JSF **passthrough elements**.

Define a new XML namespace

```
xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
```

In your html use this tag.

```
<button type="button" jsf:id="btn" jsf:outcome="yourViewIDHere">Test Button</button>
```

Comment: Native, elegant and simple. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui:fragment rendered="condition">
  button code...
</ui:fragment>
```

I think this will solve your issue

Comment: bad formatting, bad suggestion... Did you understand the question?