# dont Refresh page when click on html button

Tags: html

I have an ASP.NET web forms project.
In a Mastre page I have an input:button and input:text . when click on input:button ,page refreshed.
how can i solved it, I do not refresh a page because its not runat server contolr.
my html code in master page:

```
 <li class="menusearch">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="جستجو..." class="txtsearch" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="image" src="/statics/images/search.png" class="btnsearch" />
                    </li>
```

Comment: @mason edited and add html code .

Comment: I don't see an input button in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[W3C says](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) that `input type="image"` defines a submit button with an image. Perhaps you should change that to `button type="button"` and then put an image element inside it. Ex:

```
<button type="button" class="btnsearch">
<img src="/statics/images/search.png" />
</button>
```

Then the button won't have a submit behavior, and it'll have an image inside of it. Alternatively, you could use CSS to set a background image on your button. See [HTML / CSS How to add image icon to input type=“button”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920076/html-css-how-to-add-image-icon-to-input-type-button)