# how to put arrow sign on submit button without an image

Tags: html, css

how to put arrow sign on submit button without an image..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920076/html-css-how-to-add-image-icon-to-input-type-button

Comment: he did say without an image

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please add more details about what you want as there can be many types of "arrows signs"... Otherwise your question will be closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

arrow next to your text, will be

```
TEXT &rarr;
```

and will look like:

TEXT →

From looking at:
http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref a complete list of symbols you can create from HTML entities (symbols made from HTML special characters).

Answer (score 2):

By using Pseudo element

```css
button{position: relative; margin: 40px}
button:before{
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 10px solid transparent;
border-left: 10px solid red;
border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
right: -20px;
top: -1px;

}
```

```html
<button>ENTER</button>
```

Or use [Character Entity Reference Chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

```html
<button>ENTER &rtrif; </button>
```

Comment: to be honest I think your first answer can look somewhat more classy than my textual approach,