# Using image as a delete button

Tags: php, html, image

I can't seem to make my image a delete button.  If I do it no longer deletes from the data base.

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete></td>";
```

This is the line of code that I would like to add src = image/delete.png

Comment: you can use anchor tag instead of input tag

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920076/html-css-how-to-add-image-icon-to-input-type-button

Comment: Instead of this you can use `type image` attribute
`echo "<td>" . "<input type=image name=delete src = image/delete.png value=delete></td>";`

Comment: Thank you Super User that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a `src` nor `href` attribute to your input (you can, but that won't do anything).

To have an image displayed, either set it as the input background (using CSS), or create a DOM element (`<img src="".../>`) and add behaviour to it with javascript (register a click event, perform the request to the server you wan to do).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<button type="submit" name="delete" style="padding: 0; border: none;">
  <img src="image/delete.png" />
</button>
```

Comment: @DanBracuk cool, didn't know that. I prefer buttons over inputs since: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Image with CSS:

```
<style>
    #delete {
        width: 150px;
        height: 50px;
        border: none;
        color: transparent;
        background: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=150%C3%9750&w=150&h=50);
    }
</style>
<td><input id="delete" type=submit name=delete value=delete></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this :-

```
echo '<td><a href="delete.php"><img src="image/delete.png" /></a></td>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your image as a background of the button using css property -> `background-image`. And then use the `.btn-class` in the `input` field.

```
<style>
    .btn-class{
         background-image: url("/path/to/image");
    }
</style>
<?php echo "<td>" . '<input type="submit" class="btn-class" name="delete" value="delete"></td>'; ?>
```