# How can I add three different image button icons in this HTML code?

Tags: html, css, image, button

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input id="text" type="text" name="text">
<input type="button" name="page1" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://example.com/' + this.name + '/' + document.getElementById('text').value)">
<input type="button" name="page2" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://example.com/' + this.name + '/' + document.getElementById('text').value)">
<input type="button" name="page3" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://example.com/' + this.name + '/' + document.getElementById('text').value)">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML / CSS How to add image icon to input type="button"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920076/html-css-how-to-add-image-icon-to-input-type-button)

Comment: Do you want the buttons to have icons next to a text or that the button is a image?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add another field as below

```
<input type="button" style="height:200px;width:200px;background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhiAi.png')"/>
```

Comment: I just tried it. I put /image1.png but not working anymore

Comment: @user8481790, you have to define the path of your image. try replace and try this `src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhiAi.png"`

Comment: @user8481790, also define the height and width in the style.

Comment: How to define height and width?

Comment: @user8481790, i've attached the jsfiddle has the height and width in the html code.

Comment: The fiddle has errors. It has `<input type="button" src="image/image1.png">`