# why is my css background tranparent?

Tags: html, css

I am using a image as a background. Here is the CSS for the div

```
#bkground {
    width: 1100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: url(images/carbon_fiber2.jpg) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    /*background: black;*/
}
```

In firebug it shows up as

```
#bkground {
    background: url("images/carbon_fiber2.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1100px;
}
```

Where does the tranparent setting come from and how can I have the image show up properly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you link to the live site please?  Or a demo?

Comment: I uploaded it. What I'd like is a black background for the browser and then the image as background for the wrapper div. Currently only the browser shows up. http://www.racefightclub.com/dev/index.php

Comment: Since you said you are using firebug, can you check if the request for the url images/carbon_fiber2.jpg is successful under the "Net" tab?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bad path, the image shows it to be at 
    http://www.racefightclub.com/dev/css/images/carbon_fiber2.jpg

it should be 
    http://www.racefightclub.com/dev/images/carbon_fiber2.jpg

so either make it ../images/carbon_fiber2.jpg

or probably /dev/images/carbon_fiber2.jpg

And this is because you are referencing the image path from within your css folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think the transparent bit, is referring to the background colour, you can have a colour (as a backup if the image isn't found) and an image. Firebug is just adding the defaults that are applied that you haven't overriden. And the default for background-color is transparent. The image should still show up though if it's found, so I'm guessing it's not and instead the transparent background-color is being shown.

<del>First thing I notice is that your image url is not in quotation marks in the css. I'd try that first.</del>

So,

```
background: url('images/carbon_fiber2.jpg') ;
```

*See comments*, I've been reliably informed that quotes are not required.

Then, just a hunch, but are you including the css from a page on the root directory of your site? If not, you may need to make the path absolute, i.e.

```
background: url('/images/carbon_fiber2.jpg') ;
```

Comment: I agree with your second hunch. Also, quotation marks shouldn't matter. See answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/css-url-whats-better

Comment: @mg1075. I didn't know that. Thought the quotes were required. Thanks. That'll save a few bytes when I'm on a over optimisation kick!

Comment: thanks for the help. I don't know what caused the issue, possibly some conflicting css, but I have the effect I want on a new stylesheet and will gradually migrate everything over to see what triggered it.