# Improving HTML and CSS on using background images

Tags: html, css

Is there a better way to have the same output generated by the following code?

The *HTML* code is:

```
<div class="imaged backgrounded"></div>
<div class="title">
  Title test text
</div>
```

The *CSS* code is:

```
.imaged {
    background: transparent url("/images/sprites.png") no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    width: 24px;
}

.backgrounded {
    background-position: -16px -106px;
}

.title {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have looks fine.

Here are some trivial improvements:

- The default `background-color` [is `transparent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-color), so you don't need to specify it.
- You don't [*need* quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/css-url-whats-better/2168861#2168861) around that image `url`.
- I would put the `width` and `height` properties next to each other, because they are related.
- `display: inline-block` doesn't work on elements that aren't naturally inline in IE7, a browser that still unfortunately has [some market share](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201006-201106). If your site has any IE7 users, you should [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575).

So, this is the final result:

```
.imaged {
    background: url(/images/sprites.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}
.backgrounded {
    background-position: -16px -106px;
}
.title {
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

You should also consider changing `<div class="title">` to something more semantic, such as `h2` or `h3` depending on how important the titles are.

Yes, this is all very pedantic.

Answer (score 0):

You never create separate class for background position. you can also do like below

```
.imaged {
    background: transparent url("/images/sprites.png") -16px -106px no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 22px;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    padding: 2px 0px 0 0;
    width: 24px;
}

.title {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Why I should never create separate class for background position?

Comment: In that class you have used only background-position, that can be assing in imaged class itself.

Comment: Actually, creating separate classes for `background-image` and `background-position` can be very helpful.  It's a standard way to put, say, forty images into just one sprite image, and then have a separate class for each `background-position` defining their coordinates.  Very efficient.  Can be annoying to work out though.

Comment: What you have is fine.  What are you trying to improve?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Will, I always put my background positions on a new line.

```
.imaged {
background: transparent url("/images/sprites.png") no-repeat;
background-position: -16px -106px;
float: left;
height: 24px;
margin: 0 8px 0 0;
width: 24px;
}
```

But you can also do it the shortened way

```
background: transparent url("/images/sprites.png") no-repeat -16px -106px;
```

Comment: I think will meant that you can specify several div's to use the same background sprite, then use background position to individually position the sprite. Having the background and background-position statements as above is redundant, just merge them into background.