# css background image in a different folder from css

Tags: html, css

my css is in `assets/css/style.css` and my image is in `assets/img/bg.png` But when i try to link the background image:

```
background: url(../img/bg.png);
```

it instead uses `assets/css/../img/bg.png` as the url. Why is it?

Comment: It shouldn't... does quoting it (`background: url('../img/bg.png');`) solve the problem?

Comment: @minitech it didn't :( Also tried using double quotes

Comment: Tried on both chrome and opera.

Comment: Are you *sure* it uses that as the URL? How are you checking?

Comment: I might be being a bit too thorough, but are you checking [like this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2463964/CSS-Problem.PNG)? (As you can see, it works for me...)

Comment: Aha, thanks! Thought the console was just for js, i opened it and saw the filename was incorrect :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Html file (/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="assets/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Background Image</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Css file (/assets/css/style.css)

```
body{
    background:url(../img/bg.jpg);  
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to what you did for this. This is a basic HTML/CSS layout. Why would this make the answer as you haven't officially shown any different code than what is really provided.

Answer (score 3):

For mac OS you should use this :

```
body {
 background: url(../../img/bg.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### you can use this

`body{
    background-image: url('../img/bg.png');
}`

---

I tried this on my project where I need to set the background image of a div so I used this and it worked!

Comment: Why to use quotes in URL is answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/is-quoting-the-value-of-url-really-necessary

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but solved changing the direction of the slash sign:
For some reason when Atom copies Paths from the project folder it does so like `background-image: url(img\image.jpg\)`instead of `(img/image.jpeg)`

While i can see it's not the case for OP may be useful for other people (I just wasted half the morning wondering why my stylesheet wasn´t loading)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, but only when launching the site on hosting. In my case, the correct path to the map was the entry of the path in this form:

```css
background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.418) url("/portfolio/css/../images/load.gif") center / 50px no-repeat;
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are providing a relative pathway to the image, the image location is looked for from the location in which you have the css file. So if you have the image in a different location to the css file you could either try giving the absolute URL(pathway starting from the root folder) or give the relative file location path. In your case since img and css are in the folder assets to move from location of css file to the img file, you can use '..' operator to refer that the browser has to move 1 folder back and then follow the pathway you have after the '..' operator. 
This is basically how relative pathway works and you can use it to access resoures in different folders. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

body

{

background-image: url('../images/bg.jpeg');

}

Answer (score -4):

You are using cache system.. you can modify the original file and clear cache to show updates

Answer (score -5):

You are using a relative path. You should use the absolute path, url(/assets/css/style.css).

Comment: Relative paths work, and absolute paths aren't always the best. Maybe we could focus on the problem?