# Random Background image doesn't work in chrome?

Tags: php, background-process

I'm trying to make random background.

```
background:url(images/background/background-image.php) no-repeat fixed;
background-size: 100%;
```

it works in firefox, safari and IE, but it doesn't work in chrome.

background-image.php

```
<?php

    $folder = '.';
    $extList = array();     
    $extList['gif'] = 'image/gif';  
    $extList['jpg'] = 'image/jpeg';     
    $extList['jpeg'] = 'image/jpeg';    
    $extList['png'] = 'image/png';  

    $img = null;

    if (substr($folder,-1) != '/') { 
        $folder = $folder.'/'; 
    }

    if (isset($_GET['img'])) {  
        $imageInfo = pathinfo($_GET['img']);    
        if ( isset( $extList[ strtolower( $imageInfo['extension'] ) ] ) && file_exists( $folder.$imageInfo['basename'] ) ) {        
            $img = $folder.$imageInfo['basename'];  
        } 
    } else {    
        $fileList = array();    
        $handle = opendir($folder);     
        while ( false !== ( $file = readdir($handle) ) ) {      
            $file_info = pathinfo($file);       
            if (isset( $extList[ strtolower( $file_info['extension'] ) ] ) ) {                    
                $fileList[] = $file;        
            }   
        }   
        closedir($handle);
        if (count($fileList) > 0) {         
            $imageNumber = time() % count($fileList);       
            $img = $folder.$fileList[$imageNumber];     
        } 
    }

    if ($img!=null) {   
        $imageInfo = pathinfo($img);    
        $contentType = 'Content-type: '.$extList[ $imageInfo['extension'] ];    
        header ($contentType);  
        readfile($img); 
    } else {    
        if ( function_exists('imagecreate') ) {         
            header ("Content-type: image/png");         
            $im = @imagecreate (100, 100) or die ("Cannot initialize new GD image stream");         
            $background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255); 
            $text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0,0,0);
            imagestring ($im, 2, 5, 5,  "IMAGE ERROR", $text_color); 
            imagepng ($im); 
            imagedestroy($im);
        }
    }                                                        
?>
```

Comment: Is this what the file looked like originally?

Comment: What I think, set the header of php file as `image/jpeg`.

Comment: does it work in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a script that generates the actual image file. I would make the script reference a link to the file. For example if in directory `images` their were 10 random images I would use PHP's `rand` function with `scandir`.

**NOTE:** I have not tested the code below. It serves as a "rough idea".

```
<?php
    $website_path = "http://www.example.com/".$GET['imgpath'];
    $list = scandir($_GET['imgpath']);
    if(count($list)>0){ //yes images in directory
        $random = rand(0,count($list));
        $random_path = $list[$random];
    }else               //no images in directory
        $random_path = "/images/error.php";
    $random_path = $website_path."/".$random_path;
    echo "background:url('$random_path');";
?>
background-size:100%;
```

Also note that you did not include the single quotations around the `background:url('...');` CSS style. If I read your code right you can see that you may have over complicated matters.

Comment: Actually, you don't need quotations around the URL string for CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/css-url-are-quotes-needed

Comment: @Ochiroo Was this helpful? Did you even see my answer, or was it a complete waste of my time?

Answer (score -1):

Can you put the CSS in a PHP file, and use a variable to list the background image path?

```
background:url(<?=$bgimage?>) no-repeat fixed;
```

And have your PHP script output the variable $bgimage

Note that the shorthand

```
<?=$bgimage?>
```

is the same as saying

```
<?php echo $bgimage; ?>
```

Comment: No, <?=$bgimage?> works fine - I always use this shorthand to echo variables. All of these are equivalent <?php echo $foo; ?> <? echo $foo; ?> or <?= $foo ?>

Comment: My vote is locked unless the answer is edited according to stackoverflow.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I didn't realise you couldn't edit it. Oh well.