# Regex for background image

Tags: javascript, java, css, regex

I've made a regular expression for getting all background image patterns:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("background(-image)?:[\\s]?url[\\s]*\([\\s]*(?<url>[^\)]*)[\\s]*\)[\\‌​s]*");
```

But this will failed in this case, because of `#66cc33`:

```
background:#66CC33 url(images/bg-topbar.png)
```

Can anyone help me to modify my pattern?

Comment: Show us your pattern

Comment: If you want someone to modify your patterm, you probably need to tell us the pattern.

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("background(-image)?:[\\s]?url[\\s]*\\([\\s]*(?<url>[^\\)]*)[\\s]*\\)[\\s]*");    this is the pattern made by me.

Comment: Please include vital information in the question, not in comments.

Comment: And what other strings should it work with? Please also include those into the question itself

Comment: sorry sir ... i wrote it but i don't know why its not there.

Comment: background-image:url(a.png)    or   backgrounf:url(a.png)   or    background-image:url('a.png')    or   backgrounf:url("a.png") kind of strings can be recognized by this pattern

Comment: `backgroun` **f** is a typo, right?

Comment: its background . it was typing error. and i need to pick the a.png so i need grouping too

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex, with basically doesn't care about anything but the `url()` content:

```
background(-image)?:.*?url\(\s*(?<url>.*?)\s*\)
```

Comment: thank you sir . its working :-)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/20857448/5856415, you should try the regex given in that answer to simply select text between the brackets.

```
/\((.*?)\)/)[1].replace(/('|")/g
```