# how send comment.id to computed in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am looking for a way to send that **comment.id** in v-for to my userimage in computed property

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="comments" v-for="(comment,i) in allcomments">

            <div id="comment">
                <img class="userimg" :src="userimg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</template>
```

and this is my computed

```
computed:
            {
                allcomments()
                {
                    return this.$store.getters.comments;
                },
                userimage()
                {

                }
            },
```

I don't want to do it by methods. I just want to do that by computed

please help me.

Comment: Can you share how desired image url should look like? Also you cannot pass parameters to computed properties, so what you desire will not work.
For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522634/can-i-pass-parameters-in-computed-properties-in-vue-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as user8672473 said, it's not really possible. If you insist on using a computed property, you can make this portion of your code into a component:

```html
       <div id="comment">
            <img class="userimg" :src="userimg" alt="">
        </div>
```

reworked parent component:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="comments" v-for="(comment,i) in allcomments">

            <comment-component :comment="comment">
            </comment-component>
        </div>


    </div>
</template>
```

And this will be your `comment-component`:

```
    <template>
       <div id="comment.id">
           <img class="userImg" :src="userImg" alt="">
       <div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
        props: {
            comment: {
                type: Object
            }
        },
        computed: {
            userImg({ comment }) {
                return comment.id
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: this is what i realy want