# Using object destructuring within vue computed properties

Tags: vue.js

Is it an acceptable practice to use object destructuring within a computed property rather than using this.myData?

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return: {
      myNumber: 1
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myNumberTimesTwo({ myNumber }) {
      return myNumber * 2
    },
    myNumberTimesThree() {
      return this.myNumber * 3
    }
  }
}
<script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Computed propertuy don't receive parameters.
See this post for more deteils: [Can I pass parameters in computed properties in Vue.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522634/can-i-pass-parameters-in-computed-properties-in-vue-js)

Comment: When I use Object destructuring on a computer property as per my example, this works correctly