# Undefined error while looping through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2, computed-properties

I'm working on a rendered list of dates for an event schedule page and am having trouble rendering a list of **extraRounds**. This basically works exactly the same as the top intial instance, but I need a loop to get through the array of objects that could pontentially be added.

I have the conditional state to show the **extraRounds** if there are any, to give each item a title with the index of the event shown, but when it comes to feeding the information of each object into my computed properties I get this error:
`Expected Object, got Date`

I thought the `Date` attribute was an object itself, but I guess not

How can I get the interpolated dates to show properly without that error? Where am I going wrong with this loop?

`index.dateVotingOpenConverted` and `extraRound.dateVotingOpenConverted` both are not working.

Any pointers/ help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

**CodeSandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/event-schedule-gukrb

**EventSchedule**

```
<template>
  <div class="event-schedule-info">
    <div class="_pill _color">Round 1</div>
    <div class="_row">
      <div class="_pill _clear">Applications</div>
      <div class="_date">
        {{ dateSubmissionOpenConverted }}〜{{ dateSubmissionCloseConverted }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_row">
      <div class="_pill _clear">Voting</div>
      <div class="_date">
        {{ dateVotingOpenConverted }}〜{{ dateVotingCloseConverted }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_row">
      <div class="_pill _clear">Results</div>
      <div class="_date">{{ dateResultAnnouncementConverted }}</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div v-if="extraRounds">
      <div
        v-for="(extraRound, index) in extraRounds"
        :key="'extraRound' + index"
        class="event-schedule-info"
      >
        <div class="_pill _color">Round {{ index + 2 }}</div>
        <div class="_row">
          <div class="_pill _clear">Applications</div>
          <div class="_date">
            {{ index.dateVotingOpenConverted }}〜{{
              index.dateVotingCloseConverted
            }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_row">
          <div class="_pill _clear">Results</div>
          <div class="_date">{{ index.dateResultAnnouncementConverted }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.event-schedule-info > *
  margin-bottom: 10px

._pill
  height: 21px
  width: 83px
  left: 207px
  top: 814px
  font-size: 14px
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 400
  line-height: 21px
  letter-spacing: 0em
  text-align: center
  border-radius: 20px

._color
  color: white
  background-color: indianred

._clear
  color: indianred
  background-color: white
  border: solid 1px indianred

._row
  display: flex
  justify-content: flex-start
  align-items: center

._date
  font-family: Hiragino Maru Gothic Pro
  font-size: 18px
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 400
  line-height: 27px
  letter-spacing: 0em
  text-align: left
  padding: 0 5px

._vote
  padding-right: 5px
  text-decoration: underline
  font-family: Hiragino Maru Gothic Pro
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: normal
  font-size: 13px
  line-height: 19px
  color: indianred
</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: "EventScheduleInfo",
  props: {
    /**
     * @type {Date}
     */
    dateSubmissionOpen: { type: Object },
    /**
     * @type {Date}
     */
    dateSubmissionClose: { type: Object },
    /**
     * @type {Date}
     */
    dateVotingOpen: { type: Object },
    /**
     * @type {Date}
     */
    dateVotingClose: { type: Object },
    /**
     * @type {Date}
     */
    dateResultAnnouncement: { type: Object },
    /**
     * @type {[{ dateVotingOpen: {Date}, dateVotingClose: {Date}, dateResultAnnouncement: {Date} }]}
     */
    extraRounds: { type: Array },
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    monthDayConverted(d) {
      return d.toLocaleString("ja", { month: "long", day: "numeric" });
    },
    monthDayTimeConverted(d) {
      return d.toLocaleString("ja", {
        month: "long",
        day: "numeric",
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
      });
    },
  },
  computed: {
    dateSubmissionOpenConverted() {
      return this.monthDayConverted(this.dateSubmissionOpen);
    },
    dateSubmissionCloseConverted() {
      return this.monthDayConverted(this.dateSubmissionClose);
    },
    dateVotingOpenConverted() {
      return this.monthDayConverted(this.dateVotingOpen);
    },
    dateVotingCloseConverted() {
      return this.monthDayConverted(this.dateVotingClose);
    },
    dateResultAnnouncementConverted() {
      return this.monthDayTimeConverted(this.dateResultAnnouncement);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**HelloWorld**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <EventSchedule
      :dateSubmissionOpen="new Date('2020/06/01')"
      :dateSubmissionClose="new Date('2020/06/30')"
      :dateVotingOpen="new Date('2020/06/30')"
      :dateVotingClose="new Date('2020/07/10')"
      :dateResultAnnouncement="new Date('2020/07/14 12:00:00')"
      :extraRounds="[
        {
          dateVotingOpen: new Date('2020/07/16'),
          dateVotingClose: new Date('2020/07/26'),
          dateResultAnnouncement: new Date('2020/07/31 12:00:00'),
        },
        {
          dateVotingOpen: new Date('2020/08/20'),
          dateVotingClose: new Date('2020/08/26'),
          dateResultAnnouncement: new Date('2020/08/31 12:00:00'),
        },
        {
          dateVotingOpen: new Date('2020/09/16'),
          dateVotingClose: new Date('2020/09/26'),
          dateResultAnnouncement: new Date('2020/09/31 12:00:00'),
        },
      ]"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventSchedule from "./EventSchedule";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: { EventSchedule },
  props: {},
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just instead of `type: Object` use `type: Date` in the prop section of your component. so for example `dateSubmissionOpen` prop should look like this: `dateSubmissionOpen: { type: Date }`. it worked in the codepen you provided.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Where exactly do I put that?

Comment: in the prop types, I updated my answer so it will be clearer

Comment: Interesting. The error goes away for me, but the dates still don't render for me. I've even changed it over in the codepen and it doesn't change at all. 

And in the actual project I now get this error : **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of undefined"**

Comment: I can see you have another problem with the code, in the `otherRounds` you use `index.dateVotingOpenConverted` which i think is wrong

Comment: Ahh, yes. I was trying with `index.dateVotingOpenConverted` in the interpolation in Codesandbox, but I also tried `extraRound.dateVotingOpenConverted` and still get that same typeError.

Comment: Its because you dont have `extraRound.dateVotingOpenConverted` you have `extraRound.dateVotingOpen`, you need to use a method or create a computed property that return a function so it could get parameters. (you can also use vue filters but they are depricated in vue3) see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40539522/11545271

Comment: I think I got it working! I wound up just putting the method in the interpolation like so ` monthDayConverted(extraRounds[index].dateVotingOpen)` and now they are all rendering as I want them to!

I'm still getting a **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of undefined"** and have no idea where it's coming from, since it seems like everything is working.

Thanks for all the help up until now!