# This expression is not callable. Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures. Error in Vue3 computed property

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to create a computed property where it checks item is in the array. So i created this function that returns boolean value and takes one parameter which is the item i will check.

```
isSelected: function (item: MediaGalleryItemTypes) {
  return this.selectedItems.some(e => e._id === item._id)
}
```

In the template section i have to send the variable to another component, here is how i use it

```
 DocumentCard(:is-selected="isSelected(document)")
```

The code gives error as

```
chunk-common.js:5918 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.isSelected is not a function
```

and in vscode it gives the error as:

```
This expression is not callable. Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.
```

How can i fix this and make a computed property to get a parameter?

Comment: There's not enough context to reproduce the problem. Can you show the full component definition for that method and template?

Comment: The quick answer to your question is: by making the computed return a function. But chances are there's a simpler way: using a regular function (a.k.a. Options API method) instead of a computed. Why don't you show us the relevant code of your component? Are you using Options/Composition API? How does the relevant bit of `<template>` look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass parameters to computed properties (unless the computed return a function). You can use with the standard method

[Can I pass parameters in computed properties in Vue.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522634/can-i-pass-parameters-in-computed-properties-in-vue-js)