# How to use other getter inside setup store in Pinia?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

How can I use other getter inside setup store in Pinia?

```js
export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', () => {
  const count = ref(0)
  const name = ref('Eduardo')
  const doubleCount = computed(() => count.value * 2)
  const HOW_TO_USE = computed(() => { /* how to use doubleCount here? */ } )
  function increment() {
    count.value++
  }

  return { count, name, doubleCount, increment }
})
```

**Edit - follow-up**

If I want to pass an argument to that HOW_TO_USE , then should it be just returning a function like this?

```js
const HOW_TO_USE = computed((arg)=> /* do with arg */)
```

or actually this:

```js
const HOW_TO_USE = (arg) => computed((/*no args*/)=> /* do with arg */)
```

Comment: The same way you'd do without Pinia as doubleCount.value, setup function basically wraps composition api

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks! And if I want to pass an argument to that it then would be just returning a function like this? const HOW_TO_USE  = computed((arg)=> /* do with arg */) ?

Comment: Then you need a parametrized computed, something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/74728648/3731501