# Vue 3 Script Setup reactive computed class toggle on click

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm recently trying to learn Vue 3 with the script setup syntax.

I am dividing some content into four tabs and wish to apply the 'active' class when one is clicked. The string value itself is updating when a tab is clicked, but I cannot seem to get the computed class property to also apply.

My template:

```
<div
  @click="onTabClick('first')"
  :class="activeState('first')"
>
  <span>First</span>
</div>
<!-- repeated for second, third, and fourth... -->
```

My script setup:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed } from "vue";

let selectedTab = "";

const activeState = computed(
  () => (tab: string) => selectedTab === tab ? "active" : "inactive",
);

const onTabClick = (tab: string) => {
  selectedTab = tab;
};
</script>
```

I am thinking I have to use ref somehow to make it reactive, but I haven't been able to find a solution for this setup. Hopefully someone here might know. Is there a way to do it like this or will I have to declare a ref(false) for each tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing parameters to computed properties should generally be avoided in favor of just using normal methods. [See longer explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522634/can-i-pass-parameters-in-computed-properties-in-vue-js)

As a method:

```js
const activeState = (tab: string) => selectedTab === tab ? "active" : "inactive";
```

Another problem with your code however is the fact that the DOM won't update since no reactive variables are being updated. It's easily fixable by making `selectedTab` into a ref.  As a [ref](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref), values are assigned to it's `.value` property.

```js
const selectedTab = ref("");

const activeState = (tab: string) => selectedTab.value === tab ? "active" : "inactive";

const onTabClick = (tab: string) => {
  selectedTab.value = tab;
};
```

[Vue Playground demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqdVM1u2zAMfhVBlyZAlxx68+Lsp+iA7bANS466KDLtqJElQ6LTDEHefZScNIaXtEUPBvjzkfxIk9rzL00z2bbAMz4LyusGmZG2ygXHIDgLgG0zF1bXjfPI9sxDyQ6s9K5mglOc4B+FFVY5G5DQBhRCsZQrlkfoSHDBxz2EVKi3sECJQIgRylXGAnptqzHL5/0Ek600LYHynBGKfaJyXTCxykjR9qT20jtLkfdGq82l7Hth2aUSsQAlOdA3m3ZDoJZJQagbQ1RJY2xW6G0SOrGTPqtYjKZ1rjy6KbUPeDOm3hMmU0aGQJhe8/+Bjpkpd2iknX+LXiIT5WPN6aX6VxgEoHkU5+zXSAxxAxaL5H4/DVxr/wYWA9iAxDJ638+hdK3H9eskhrjhD0nuKzRO0mza2xhSA/41UZx0lboFXEm1qbxrbfFBOeN8xioPYGn5GDsantYaIW5kWsiUhN/SQdLfKHU1eQzO0r2mbIIrVzfagP/VoKYjEDzr6kSfNMY9/Ug29C3cnuxqDWpzwf4YdtEm+G8PAXy8rmcfSl8Bdu6HxU/YkfzsrF3RGkK/4PwDwZk2cuxgX2kCRLuHS2y/p5eGTnYZHnYINpyaikQj8pDw6fG5f6H1M927yV2Ko3nywz/ZOJba)

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is indeed the way!