# Vuejs how to pass image url as prop to be used as css variable for css animation

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a component that has a hover animation where 4 images are rotated in a loop:

`animation: changeImg-1 2.5s linear infinite;`

```
@keyframes changeImg-1 {
  0%, 100% { background-image: url('images/wel1.png'); }
  25% { background-image: url('images/wel2.png'); }
  50% { background-image: url('images/wel3.png'); }
  75% { background-image: url('images/wel4.png'); }
}
```

Now I want to make this component reusable by being able to pass image strings in as props, those get assigned as css variables which then get picked up by the animation.

I got as far as defining the css variable with a path in a computed property which is then used in the css:

```
computed: {
    userStyle () {
      return {
        '--myBackground': `url(${require('@/components/ImagesInText/images/wel1.png')})`,
      }
    }
  },
```

CSS:

```
.image {  
background:var(--myBackground); 
}
```

What I can't get to work is to pick up an image path from props and use it in the computed property...

```
   props: {
    image: { type: String, default: '@/components/ImagesInText/images/wel1.png' },
  },
```

If I do this below I get en error: Cannot find module '@/components/ImagesInText/images/wel1.png'"

```
computed: {
    userStyle () {
      return {

        '--myBackground': `url(${require( this.image )})`,
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a variable path/filename, `require` needs some assistance. You must hard code at least the first portion of the path as a string.

- For example, this works:

```js
const filename = 'wel1.png';
require('@/components/ImagesInText/images/' + filename); // <-- The string is needed
```

- This works too:

```
const path = 'components/ImagesInText/images/wel1.png';
require('@/' + path); // <-- This is good enough too
```

- But this would ***not*** work:

```js
const fullpath = '@/components/ImagesInText/images/wel1.png';
require(fullpath); // <-- No. Can't infer the path from a variable only
```

Answer (score 0):

As the way mentioned In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105099/12719616) thread. it's working perfectly for me.

```
<div class="register-img" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + require('@/assets/images/register-image.png') + ')'}"></div>
```