# Images wont load from v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have v-for loop in html, in my localhost everything works fine, but whenever I deploy to production I keep getting this error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null` , even though the url exists in the objects.

```js
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: (`url(${item.cover_media.url}`)}")></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591429/16897778

This is the only item I have and u can see the image is loaded

but console still throws
and whenever I add more items, it can't fetch more than 1. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: it looks like your `item` or `cover_media` property is `null`. Have you verified that these are not null using a devtool?

Comment: I think the issue is the component renders before the cover_media is here, how can I make sure the url will load whenever it exists?

Comment: Make sure each item's cover_media value is not null.  If not sure, use `item.cover_media?.url` instead.

Comment: @ruoyanli will it not return undefined and not load the item?

Comment: AFAIR vue object properties are reactive; it will load nothing at first, then update the values when `.url` has changed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. You can use the following code as an example:

‍‍‍‍‍‍`:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + item.cover_media.url + ')' }"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned that that the component renders before cover_media is fetched, you can give a default value to the url like so:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <div :style="{ backgroundImage: (`url(${item?.cover_media?.url || default_image_url}`)}")></div>
</div>
```

So the default image will be loaded then once the images load, it will change to the url in `item?.cover_media?.url`

Another thing you can do is only load that element after your data is fetched.

You can easily do that but here's a simple excerpt:

```
<template v-if="fetched">
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <div :style="{ backgroundImage: (`url(${item?.cover_media?.url}`)}")></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
data() {
   return {
      fetched: false,
      items: []
   }
},
methods: {
    fetchImages() {
        const response = await executeGetRequest()

        if (response.status === 200) {
            this.items = response.data.items;
            this.fetched = true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

PS. I was eating a banana while I saw this question and noticed your username so I felt inclined to answer this question haha