# Vue.js & Laravel - New Image file cannot be loaded but the older image can

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a Vue.js and Laravel project where the Vue is inside the resources/js directory of the Laravel project.

I'm having a problem with loading an image that I just put inside the resources/js/assets directory. I'm using a template so there are few images inside the folder already, and when I tried to load a new image file that I just put, the image won't be loaded. But when I tried to load the other image (which is the older image inside the directory) the image showed up. I'm trying to add the image as the background image of the page. Here is my code to do it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page-header align-items-start min-vh-100" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + bgImage + ')' }">
```

**Vue (JS):**

```
export default {
    name: "login",
    data() {
        return {
            bgImage: "/assets/img/office-dark.jpg"
        };
    }
```

I tried every new image file and that is when the problem occurred (no errors, the image just won't be loaded). The old image files are okay. Any suggestions?

Comment: think about the missing character in `'url(' bgImage + ')'` - or do `\`url(${bgImage})\``

Comment: *when I tried to load a new image file that I just put* - so, the browser doesn't notice that you changed the file on the server? it won't, until you reload the page

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I tried the 'url(${bgImage})' and fixed the missing character ('+') but still the new image won't be loaded

Comment: @Bravo I reloaded the page every time I changed something but the problem is still the same. The new image file won't show up, but when I change to old image file (any old image file) the image showed up

Comment: oh ... so, changing the value of `bgImage` doesn't work, or are you changing the image file itself? I'm confused

Comment: I didn't change the image file, I just added a new image file into the directory, and changed the image path in the file, but the new image did not show up. But when I tried to change it to another file except for the file that I just add, the image showed up. Is there something I should do with cache things?

Comment: if you're using laravel, you should put image in public folder. Then just call the image as usual

Comment: @AlvinIndra Thank you for the suggestion. It works, but I am still curious why does the new image file couldn't be loaded using the js

Comment: it can, it's just that you don't understand your build environment well enough to know what you're doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look here, often `require` is a good choice.

Link: [Vue.js data-bind style backgroundImage not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242272/vue-js-data-bind-style-backgroundimage-not-working)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm sure I'll use require in the future to do such things.