# Background property (css) not working, image doesn't display

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to use the background link css property selector within WordPress for the image appear on it's page http://launique.co.uk/services-float/

First I used the default image link and entered the link to the default image, which I had uploaded to the media library:

`background: url(http://launique.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/fold.gif) no-repeat 0 0;`

That didn't work.

Then after some research, I created a separate "images" folder within the child themes folder in my cpanel.

`background: url(images/fold.gif) no-repeat 0 0;`

But still to no avail...

This is the whole like of code:

```
.page-services h1::after { 
 content: ''; 
 display: block; 
 height: 40px; 
 width: 40px; 
 background: url(images/fold.gif) no-repeat 0 0; 
}
```

Comment: What is the `0 0` for?

Comment: I edited my answer below after testing it via Inspect Element.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38668570/4298604

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the HTML code on your site and I didn't find a H1 child elememt in the parent element div.page-services.  Therefore your CSS rule will not work. There is, however, an H3 child element.  When I altered your code in the debugger to .page-services h3::after{ ... } the image appeared.

Comment: This is incorrect. The spec does not require quotes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/is-quoting-the-value-of-url-really-necessary

Comment: Hi there, appreciate the attempt but that use of quotation marks didn't make a difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: **YES!!!** That's the one, you're the man @Jon Wilson! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: This should definitely work.

```
.page-services {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.page-services h3::after { 
  content: ''; 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px; 
  width: 40px; 
  background: url('http://launique.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/fold.gif') no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve Ventimigilia, changing the header tag from H1 to H3 worked.

Comment: You can always test this type of thing by right-clicking on the page and choosing Inspect Element.  Then, by right-clicking on the HTML and selecting "Edit As HTML", you're always free to use that as a temporary sandbox (where the changes will disappear once you refresh the browser.)  Adding <style>...</style> tags with CSS inside of them will give you the freedom of experimenting without accidentally saving too many changes in a file (aka 'bloat'.)  I primarily use Firefox (which is kind of the in-between browser with neutral cross-compatibility), and you can simply right-click and type "Q".

Comment: Appreciate the tips @Steve Ventimigilia I'll make a note of it.