# Angular SCSS proper way of writing url()

Tags: angular, sass

I've seen the option where URL in SCSS was specified without quotes like `background: url(/path/to/image.jpg);`. However, I'm using this with quotes `background: url(/path/to/image.jpg);` and this works although PhpStorm stresses these URLs due to problems with directory resolve.

Is there any difference between both options? Should be any used instead of another? Just in case this would help - I'm storing my images in `assets` sub folders.

---

This is not just about CSS it's about **SCSS** therefore I'm sure that question which is marked as duplicate of is no suitable for my question.

SCSS works in different way since it should be compiled before. If there is a wrong URL a compiler would throw an error about path resolving problem. Also, Angular moves assets from their initial positions. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is quoting the value of url() really necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/is-quoting-the-value-of-url-really-necessary)

Answer (score -1):

Quotes are optional.

You need them only when you want to add special characters or the component variables like below.

For eg:

```
 [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'}">
```

where `image` is a component variable

Comment: I've asked about SCSS. Not template

Comment: I have just shown a usage of `url()`. where quotes are must. It happened that it is in the template. Also, my answer has clearly mentioned when you need it and when not. This does not deserve a downvote