# Some images not working in `background-image:url()`

Tags: html, css

Some images not working in `background-image:url()`, i cant figure out that does i need to remove `(` and `)` from image name or anything else is an issue?

any help will be appreciated.

here is an working and not working examples.

```html
<!-- Not Working -->

<div style="background-image:url(https://ignite.galify.com/images/tx9gyzjfb24712-(1).jpg)"> img </div>


<!-- Working -->

<div style="background-image:url(https://ignite.galify.com/images/9mspqz9gqb1561725209327568845756.jpg)"> img1 </div>
```

Comment: You can always encode parts of the URL: replace `(` by `%28` and `)` by `%29`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks it is useful for be because `background-image:url()` generated dynamically from thirparty library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape special characters (`\` in front of `(` and `)`) in the URL.

```html
<!-- Use CSS escape character to escape special characters -->

<div style="background-image:url(https://ignite.galify.com/images/tx9gyzjfb24712-\(1\).jpg)"> img </div>


<!-- Working -->

<div style="background-image:url(https://ignite.galify.com/images/9mspqz9gqb1561725209327568845756.jpg)"> img1 </div>
```

Alternatively, use single quote (`'`) to enclose the image URL:

```html
<!-- Use single quote (') to enclose image URL -->

<div style="background-image:url('https://ignite.galify.com/images/tx9gyzjfb24712-(1).jpg')"> img </div>
<!-- Working-->

<div style="background-image:url(https://ignite.galify.com/images/9mspqz9gqb1561725209327568845756.jpg)"> img1
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add single quotation marks around the url. If you have special characters in your URL, you should use quotes or escape the characters. Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/is-quoting-the-value-of-url-really-necessary) a read for further information.

```html
Now Working

<div style="background-image:url('https://ignite.galify.com/images/tx9gyzjfb24712-(1).jpg')"> img </div>


Working

<div style="background-image:url(https://ignite.galify.com/images/9mspqz9gqb1561725209327568845756.jpg)"> img1 </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add single quotes into `url`:

```
<div style="background-image:url('https://ignite.galify.com/images/tx9gyzjfb24712-(1).jpg')"> img </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had an issue with some urls containing a single quote. Fixed it surrounding the url with ***`&quot;`***:

```
<div style="background-image: url(&quot; ${url} &quot;);"></div>
```