# Background picture is not showing CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

Beginner, learning basics in HTML/CSS
I have an issue with the background image.
When i code it with outside link like this it is working:

```
 background-image: url(https://furniturefusion.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/inspiration-banner1-2.jpg);
```

When i do it with a downloaded picture (same picture), the image is not showing in a browser.

```
background-image: url(/images/cover.jpg);
```

I assume all other (height, weight) is good, since it is working with http.... And image is in the same folder where is index page and style folder.

Where is the problem?

Comment: your url for internal resources is looking for a folder named images. Remove it to access the image

Comment: Please check the console for image is not loading error. The syntax is right , the only issue could be the path of the image or spelling.

Answer (score 2):

If your image is in the same folder as index and css then the url should be:

```
background-image: url("cover.jpg");
```

Using

```
background-image: url("/images/cover.jpg");
```

you are referring to an image that is in a subfolder named images (that you don't have)
Obviously I assume that the missing quotes are just a typo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/is-quoting-the-value-of-url-really-necessary

Answer (score 1):

it will likely be because your path is now incorrect.  If you open up the chrome developer tools (F12 on keyboard) go to network, then refresh the page. You should see the image in there in red.  You need to adjust the path so it is correct.

the start of the URL matters.  Starting with a `'/'` will start from the website root. `'.'` will do current directory and `'..'` will go up a directory.

so if your path is:

```
www.example.com/images/test/cover.jpg
```

and you start in:

```
www.example.com/css/
```

doing `/images/test/cover.jpg` would be `www.example.com/images/test/cover.jpg` as then starting `'/'` makes it start from the root.

doing `images/test/cover.jpg` would be `www.example.com/css/images/test/cover.jpg` as this doesnt start with a `'/'`.

you could do: `../images/test/cover.jpg` as this would then be `www.example.com/images/test/cover.jpg`