# Adding background image to a box element

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie. I'm finding it hard to  add background image to a box element. I've tried resetting the code, moving it to a new folder, resizing the image and changing the class but nothing works. The image doesn't show in the box When I inspect the element on Chrome, it says error file not found.

This is the CSS below

```css
.static-width{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #606060;
    background-image: url(Images\millylogo.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: if you think, the path of the image is not the problem,then once check the extension of the image.Many mistake this. for example: jpg and jpeg are different

Comment: Your image path is probably wrong. Try to use **slash (/)** instead of  **backslash**  \

Comment: Thank you 0stone0

Meanwhile, I copy the image path directly from the server
The extension can't be wrong, can it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your path is not wright. You must to put the right path (absolute or relative) into the property. You should create a repository with your project and put all your files into it.
A good documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: Could you please add the source? [Is quoting the value of url() really necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/is-quoting-the-value-of-url-really-necessary)

Comment: You've right, I didn't know that. I edit my post to fix this

Comment: Thank you Quentin,

 Meanwhile, I copy the image path directly from the server The url or extension can't be wrong, can it?

Comment: Can you put here the architecture of your project ?