# why background image is not loading my css file

Tags: html, wordpress, css-selectors, background-image, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to load background image so I'm using the CSS background image URL but it is not working, which means it is not loading.

```css
.home {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(../wordpress/img/online-training.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="home" id="home">
  <div class="content">
    <span>Take The Right Step <br>For Your Business</span>
    
    <p>Tax associate is a leading consultancy firm that provides simple, effective company registration and accounting solutions to enterprises in ireland</p>
    
    <a href="#" class="btn">Get Started</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `../wordpress/img/online-training.jpg`

Check this path is even correct or not. Possibly its not able to find image there

Comment: open up the network panel in your developer tools and look to see what the requests says.

Comment: It's not good practice to use relative URL paths in a CMS environment. Depending on where the content is loaded the path may vary. Use absolute URLs or dynamically-generated paths.

Answer (score 1):

That filepath won't work. In a wordpress site, you should use the available wordpress variables and functions, similar to this:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/online-training.jpg">
```

In the above case the filepath would point to a file called "online-training.jpg"  inside a directory called "images" which is a direct child of the directory of the used Wordpress theme, pointed to by an absolute filepath.

It says "stylesheet_directory", but the stylesheet most of the time *is* a direct child of the theme directory.

If that's not the case, you can use `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` (which *is*  the theme directory) instead, and if necessary, add additional filepath details which lead to the directory that contains the image.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like the URL may not be correct. Try using the full URL and see if it loads e.g. `https://website.com/wordpress/img/online-training.jpg`. If that works then the relative URL syntax you're using may need adjusting e.g. `/wordpress/img/online-training.jpg`.

It will work without quotes but its better to have them in as suggested below.

Comment: Why is it 'better' to have them in? The spec doesn't mandate them (apart from if there are special characters).

Answer (score -1):

you have a wrong link
if u want to get a pic from the internet with out downloading it
you should right click on the pic copy image address and paste in for example

```
 .home {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
min-height: 100vh;
 background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615789591457- 74a63395c990?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YmFieSUyMGNhdHxlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80);  
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;`
```

hope that help :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Your css is missing double quotes in the URL for background-image :

**CSS :**

`background-image: url("../wordpress/img/online-training.jpg");`

Moreover, you should check your file's path.

Comment: While spec may call for quotes, I've been omitting them for a couple decades without issue.

Comment: Quotes are optional - needed if there are special characters otherwise can be ommitted. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/is-quoting-the-value-of-url-really-necessary