# Blogger issue with custom background images on Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, safari, google-chrome, blogger

This is weird, the site in question is [blog.andrebatista.info](http://blog.andrebatista.info) and it is a hosted at blogger.com. I'm trying to make the blogger template look the same as the one in my main website, [www.andrebatista.info](http://www.andrebatista.info).

For some reason if I go directly to the blog address Chrome and Safari fail to display all of my background images... all of them.

However if I first go to [www.andrebatista.info](http://www.andrebatista.info) first and then go to the blog it renders just fine ?¿

The way I'm customizing it is by adding a link to my main site's stylesheet at the very end of the head tag on the blogger template. That stylesheet is displayed below:

*{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     border:0;
    }

```
html,body {
 background:#064169 url(http://www.andrebatista.info/images/main_gradient_slice.jpg) repeat-x;
 font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
 font-size:18px;
}

#main_wrapper{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:1024px;
}
 #header{
  background: url(http://www.andrebatista.info/images/header.jpg);
  height:133px;
  border:none;
  margin:0;
 }

 #menu_wrapper{
  background: url(http://www.andrebatista.info/images/menu.jpg);
  height:34px;
  overflow:hidden;

 }
  #menu_wrapper .menu_item{
   color:white;
   float: left;
   border: 1 px solid red;
   height: 34px;
   padding-top:10px; 
   text-align:center;
   width:100px;

  }

  #menu_wrapper .first{
   padding-left:240px;
   float:left;
   width:100px;

  }
  #menu_wrapper .active,#menu_wrapper .menu_item:hover{
   background-color:white;
   color:Teal;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

 #content_area_wrapper{
  background: url(http://www.andrebatista.info/images/body_bg_slice.jpg) repeat-y;
 }
  #content_area{
   min-height:524px;
   background: url(http://www.andrebatista.info/images/main_content_top.jpg) repeat-x;
  }
   #main_banner{
    background: url(http://www.andrebatista.info/images/main_banner.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    width:662px;
    height:338px;
    margin: 0 auto;

   }
   #main_banner div{
    color:white;
    padding-left:47px;
    padding-right:164px;
    padding-top:105px;
   }
   #text_area{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:662px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:14px;
   }
    #contentList{
     padding:0 20px 20px 20px;
    }
    #text_area .left{
     width:50%;
     float:left;
    }
    #text_area .left{
     width:50%;
     float:right;    
    }

 #footer2{
  background: url(http://www.andrebatista.info/images/footer.jpg);
  height:62px;
 }

 #footer{
  background: url(http://www.andrebatista.info/images/footer.jpg);
  height:62px;
 }
```

Any ideas on what I could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with the CSS or the server your blog is hosted on, but a problem with the server your website is hosted on. When I inspect the traffic with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), I get these responses in return, instead of the images:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 05 Mar 2010 23:43:52 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.hosting.zymic.com/403
Content-Length: 216
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Via: 1.1 www.andrebatista.info
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.hosting.zymic.com/403">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

I'm guessing this is the result of some sort of anti-hotlinking measure based on the Referer header.

Comment: Ok... I wonder if zymic does that sort of thing on purpose so that they can get some money from me... Is there a solution? I will try to host the images somewhere else... Thx!!

Comment: @hdx I don't think there's any way around it: http://www.zymic.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=13288. As for Firefox, they don't send the Referer header by default in this case: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader

Comment: U Tha Man! I moved all images to imageboo, created a different stylesheet for the blog using imageboo's direct link and now life is beautiful! My pc was about to learn how to fly but u saved it lol. Also, thanks for the link for fiddler!

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I go there in Firefox I get an error saying "no posts match my query" which make me wonder if your server isn't set up right.

EDIT: Also true in Chrome

Comment: That's because I haven't posted anything yet, I doubt it has anything to do with the css issues, also it's hosted on blogger.com so I'm pretty sure it's not a server isuue.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the URL in quote marks. (If it's not a server issue, as in the other answer, webkit might be choking on '://'.)

```
background:#064169 url("http://www.andrebatista.info/images/main_gradient_slice.jpg") repeat-x;
```

More info: [CSS background-image - What is the correct usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage)

Comment: @hdx Probably unrelated, but I ran your CSS through a validoator, and #menu_wrapper .menu_item needs to have the space between 1 and px taken out (1 px -> 1px).