# CSS url() function: Browser support

Tags: css, function, url, cross-browser

I have seen in the comments of [Is quoting the value of url() really necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/css-url-whats-better) and [CSS background-image - What is the correct usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage) that Mac IE 5 does not support quotation marks inside the url() function.

Also PPK's CSS page does not mention the url() function at all:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

So I would like to know what browser support is like for this function. What browsers recognise the value, which ones require what quotation marks, whitespace, and so on.

I realise that everything released in the past five years probably support all syntaxes. It's the older browsers I am thinking of.

Comment: IE5 Mac? It's ancient history, forget about it.

Comment: Well, everything released in the past 10 years, excluding IE 5.1 and 5.2 for Mac, supports the `url()` function.

Comment: @thirtydot: i am just curious

Answer (score 1):

Mac IE5? Serious? :) I think this browser is seriously outdated and not being used anymore :)

Anyhow, according to W3C, it's
`body {background-image:url('paper.gif');}`

And it works for all (older) browsers. For who are you developing if you need support for this kind of ancient browsers?

Comment: According to W3C, it doesn't matter whether you use quotes as long as they match (i.e. not `url('foo")`).

Comment: Your answer, besides being wrong, doesn't attempt to answer the question I asked.

Comment: Kind of rude to give everyone a vote down who is not agreed with your way of thinking... IE5 is history, serious. Stop trying to get this old-timer back to live.

Answer (score 1):

I have never ever had any issues with background-image for any browser type.

Unless of course you are putting it as a div with no content and not specifying the width and hight of the element...

example usage of background/background-image

```
#body {background-image:url('mylovelybg.jpg');}
```

or the long hand (to allow for color and repeating factors

```
#body {background:url ('mylovelybg.jpg') repeat-x #fff;}
```

Comment: I asked for browser compatibility, not a syntax example.

Comment: I clearly stated in my first line "I have never ever had any issues with background-image for any browser type.

Unless of course you are putting it as a div with no content and not specifying the width and hight of the element..." So why the down vote? I was trying to give you more information that you orginally requested - I.E help out! Why the down vote?!