# Previous and next links

Tags: jquery, css, asp-classic

I am trying to display the previous and next buttons, but as I compile it it just give me the link saying 'previous' and 'next' instead of the image I want. Below here I am showing first the code in CSS;

```css
div#slideshow ul#nav li#prev a
{
    background: url(Resources/Icons/previous.png);
}

div#slideshow ul#nav li#next a
{
    background: url(Resources/Icons/next.png);
}
```

Then here I am showing how I am calling it from asp;

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li id="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <li id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any suggestions of what the problem could be?

Comment: @Rayan first it's not good to use UPPERCASE in folder name

Comment: add `../` until root folder EX: `background: url(../Resources/Icons/next.png);`

Comment: maybe just use background-image and place the file path in single quotes

Comment: I tryed in my machine. It works fine. Maybe the paths?

Comment: If you get this working, you might also want to add text-decoration: none; to your CSS, as I have a feeling one of the browsers will want to try underline your image and probably cause some weird dots or dash artifacts under the image.

Comment: Look on the networking tab of your developer tools, it will tell you what path it is trying to get those images from.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
<a href="#">Previous</a>
```

... will give you a hyperlink with "Previous" as the text.  Your CSS might add a background to the list item, but you will still only end up with a hyperlink.

Examples of alternatives:

```
<input type="image" src="/path/to/image.gif" />

<a href="GoHere.html"><img src="/path/to/image.gif" alt="My Image" /></a>

<img src="/path/to/image.gif" alt="My Image" onclick="SomeJavaScript();" />
```

Comment: So what you suggest to do inorder to have an image of prev and next.

Comment: You would be better off having an image button, an image wrapped in anchor tags or an image with an onclick event wired up in JavaScript.

Comment: I've added a few examples above.

Comment: Trying to add a background to an anchor tag, even with the correct quoting and paths in the CSS, doesn't sound right (as far as mark-up goes).  An anchor tag isn't a block item and isn't designed to have a background image, even if it might somehow work.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is valid in the sense that an image would appear behind the innerHTML of the `<a></a>`.

Problem is most likely an issue with the path to the `PNG` - try putting the png in the same folder as the html file and using `url(next.png)`

Comment: Have you checked the PNG has no excess white area that might be thicker than the height of the `<a href>`? assuming this isn’t the problem I can only presume something else is styling the element, try `background: url(Resources/Icons/next.png) !Important;` - if that still does not work, make sure the path is correct relative to the CSS file (not applicable if your css in in-head - but very important if your css is in a `<link rel="stylesheet">` in another directory)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure CSS file paths are relative to the CSS file, not the HTML page.

Comment: quoting is not necessary, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage)

Comment: @ADC thanks for the correction, did not realise they were optional. Amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The url path you are passing in is relative to the location of the stylesheet. So if your style sheet is found at /styles/css/themes.css then the background image here will be looked for at /styles/css/Resources/Icons/XXX.png. Is that where they are being stored?

Answer (score 0):

you are using an anti-pattern [Be Specific when Needed](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/jquery-patterns/specific-when-needed.html)

use the following instead.
    #prev a {
                ...
            }

```
#next a {
           ...
        }​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting the background of a tag as it is an inline element.

You should instead insert an inner element and set the style of it to accomondate your image display.

```
<div id="slideshow">         
<ul id="nav">             
    <li id="prev"><a href="#" title="prev"><div></div></a></li>             
    <li id="next"><a href="#" title="next"><div></div></a></li>         
</ul>
```

​
Also as you have given your a tags ids you can shorten your css definition considerably by specifying them directly.

```
#prev a div
{             
background: url(http://images.all-free-  download.com/images/graphicmedium/button_previous_89678.jpg);
height : 200px;
width : 200px;       
} 


#next a div
{             
background: url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/button_next_89675.jpg);
height : 200px;
width : 200px;            
} ​
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas_Murray/T6kS6/3/) for a working example