# Background image not showing in Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image

I'm trying to set a background image on 1 of the pages in my Rails 3 app, but it's not showing.

What am I doing wrong?? Here is the relevant code:

```
<div class="hero-unit" style="background: url('public/assets/fks.JPG') ;">
```

Thanks,

Faisal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="hero-unit" style="background: url('assets/fks.JPG') ;>
```

Better still:

```
<div class="hero-unit" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'fks.JPG' %>) ;>
```

Comment: You should use the 2nd method because the first method is in relative URL.

Comment: will do. weird that the code seems to work fine even with the missing double quote..

Comment: @hikmatyar: That's just the browser being forgiving and (correctly) fixing your HTML behind your back, don't depend on it though.

Comment: @hikmatyar, like what "mu is too short" said, quotes are quite optional. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage Your problem is not the quote, but the path of the assets.