# How to get this CSS Right?

Tags: asp.net, css

The more I work with CSS, the more depression I get
I want to set a background picture stored on the same folder where my aspx and cs files
are located, still it wont put a background picture:

```
/* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

body   
{
    background-image:url(banner.gif);
    display:block; // have tried without it as well, no change :(
}
```

Default.aspx:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help how to set the background picture ?

Comment: Is that in an external file? The path to the image needs to be relative to the CSS file.

Comment: are you sure the image is correctly referenced? because as it stands banner.gif would have to be located in the root of the ~/Styles directory

Comment: check your browser's dev tools and look at the http requests being made. I'd be willing to bet that the browser is trying to load the image but it's getting a 404 error. You probably just need to change the path. Oh, and the `display:block` is completely unnecessary; that's the default for the body element anyway.

Comment: background-image:url('banner.gif');

note the two `'` i added

Comment: @DiederikEEn - [Quotes are not required](http://stackoverflow.com/q/851724/73226)

Comment: No luck, tried with surrounding with single quotes yes the structure is:
Root:
- Styles (folder)
  --it contains a css file: Site.css, whose CSS I posted in start
- banner.gif
- Site.Master
- Default.aspx

after all its just a simple Asp.Net web application
created using VS 2010

Comment: Please do not answer your question with 'additional details'. You can edit your question or post comments.

Comment: @UsmanWaheed remove the ~ from ` <link href="~/Styles/Site.css"`

Answer (score 0):

You said that your CSS and image are in same folder where you've your `aspx` file and CSS so

First try setting a background color for body say

```
body {
   background: #f00; /*This should give you red*/
}
```

If this works than fine, something is wrong with the image path, if you fail to see the color too, that means your stylesheet is at the wrong path, so instead of

```
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Should be

```
<link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: @DiederikEEn Didn't got you

Comment: ` where my aspx and cs files are located` the image is in the root. Css could be in the map styles

Comment: @DiederikEEn All the files are in a single directory according to me `background picture stored on the same folder where my aspx and cs files are located`

Comment: I Posted the paths on first
and NO :( setting any color background is not working either :(

Comment: Alien, how to get it right then ? with all my knwoledge
I cant figure out whats wrong with referencing it in master page:
`<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server"/>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>`

Comment: @UsmanWaheed Try this and see `<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` (Assuming that you are using on about.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

here is the image, I dont thin there is any problem with paths:
[image]

Comment: ignore the inline body styling as only thing works
my requirement is to get it work from Site.css file I m using Windows XP, VS 2010