# Changing a background image upon 1st click - then changing it back again on the 2nd click with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, image, onclick, toggle

I have a div element who's background image I want to change upon clicking the div - and then have the image change back to the original upon clicking once more. Div CSS code is below, showing its Class and ID:

```
.tab_box
{
width:2%;
height:20%;
position:absolute;
left:100%;
}

#tab_box1
{
background:url('cars.png') no-repeat center center;
background-size:120%;
-moz-background-size:120%;
-o-background-size:120%;
-ms-background-size:120%;
}
```

I have 3 other divs all using the same "class", then each has an individual "id" to give them seaprate images.

I tried the following j-query/css using toggleClass but its does not seem to work:

```
.one
{
width:2%;
height:20%;
background:url('mots.png') no-repeat center center;
background-size:120%;
position:absolute;
left:100%;
}
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tab_box1').click(function() {
$('#tab_box1'').toggleClass("one")
});
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong, or what method other than toggleClass could be used to switch the image to and fro?

Comment: Looks like an extra tick mark in the toggleClass line.

Comment: THanks - however even when removed, the above code still does not work

Comment: I think you're not being specific enough with your declaration in the CSS. Try changing `.one` to `#tab_box1.one`.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that toggling a class does not remove the existing class-- it simply will add `.one` or remove `.one`. You don't have to redefine all of the styles-- only the background.

Comment: thanks Chad for the note about the not needing to re-define all the styles - tidied up the code a little :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because of [css rule precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the `id rule` has precedence over `class rule`.

In your case the id rule `#tab_box1` is having background image set, then you are trying to change it using a class rule `.one`.

One nasty fix is to use [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) in the class rule like

```
.one {
    width:2%;
    height:20%;
    background:url('http://placehold.it/32/f00000') no-repeat center center !important;
    background-size:120%;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/23srv/)

The right fix will be is to use classes instead of id here, like

```
<div class="tab_box tab_box1">sadfsdf</div>
```

instead of

```
<div id="tab_box1" class="tab_box">sadfsdf</div>
```

then

```
.tab_box1
{
background:url('cars.png') no-repeat center center;
background-size:120%;
-moz-background-size:120%;
-o-background-size:120%;
-ms-background-size:120%;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MBVRW/)

Comment: Right gotcha - so is there a way of changing the image without altering the class? Is there a way to toggle the "id" instead?

Comment: Don't change what you're targeting, change how you specify the original styles. Use a class in your CSS instead of an ID.

Comment: Thanks Arun - the "nasty" fix works, however my concern is why is it considered a nasty fix? would it cause complications further down the line ie with different browsers etc?

Comment: @SamFridayWelch because I hate using `!important`... the second solution is better

Comment: @SamFridayWelch the reason is any future changes by other css rules may not reflect because of the `!important` definition

Comment: Thanks Arun - The second solutions works great, I will use this instead of the !important fix. Thank you for all your help on this one

Answer (score 0):

This will make the div behave like a button, swapping to a different image when mouse is held down, and reverting back to the original image when mouse button is released.

```
$("#button1").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(image2.jpg)'}) 
}).mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(image1.jpg)'}) 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="button1" style="background-image:url('image1.jpg');"></div>
```

Sources/References:

[CSS background-image - What is the correct usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage)

[changing the background image on mouse down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584516/changing-the-background-image-on-mouse-down)