# background image in css div tag

Tags: css, image, html, background

This has been driving me mad for hours. Please someone explain to me why no image is appearing at all. I'm using XHTML 1.0 strict. Many thanks.

CSS:

```
#flags {
    position: relative;
    background-image:url(example.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 18px;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="flags">
   <p>text
     <br />
       text
     <br/>
   </p>

   <ul>
       <li>list1</li>
       <li>list2</li>
       <li>list3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have you given image path correct?

Comment: `https://example.png` is not a proper URL.

Comment: Yes, without a doubt. It ends in .png and when copy/pasted into he browser bring me to it.

Comment: Does the browser allow mixed content? Http and https?

Comment: Just to be clear, I have an actual image in there, its just part of a coursework assignment and I dont want paste a link to the university severs. And yes, I have another https image working fine.

Comment: Where is the image stored?

Comment: Can you do <img src="your example.ping"/> on your page? Anything in the console?

Comment: @mplungjan would you care to explain further? Many thanks!

Comment: @ralph.m Just on the university's website. We were given the link.

Comment: Have you tried using that link?

Comment: Can you change your page to include a standard image link to test that the page handles the image at all. Can you hit f12 and see if there are issues in the console or network tab (chrome)

Comment: @ralph.m Yes, it is fully working. Im baffled by this.

Comment: @mplungjan It shows no reference to this image. Is that strange?

Comment: @user2962713: see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22189494/1516616) given below

Comment: Have you check the image in the browser. that is, have you open the url of the image (https://example.png) in browser?

Comment: @gunaseelan Yes I have opened it and it works fine. When I press F12 there is no reference to this image however.

Answer (score 2):

when you calling image using `background-image` please make sure to define the `width` and `height` property.

this is your CSS code and I added `height` and `width`

```
#flags {
position: relative;
background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom right;
float: left;
width:100%; //width:200px; /* added the width 100% is good for responsive */ 
height:auto; //height:200px; /* added the height For Responsive*/ 
}
```

Here is the working Demo. http://jsbin.com/lonarezu/1/edit

Comment: are you using other CSS code as well, might be possible collapsing somewhere.

Comment: it would be good if you make a jsbin Demo link with actual image path.. then we can find actual problem

Comment: just checked.. you update the question.. but since you using secure server it asked for login details

Answer (score 1):

try url in single quotes

```
.test{
    width:100%;
    height:415px;
    background-image:url('http://static.fkids.ru/photo/2011/07/2380/Diana-Pentovich5461568.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcpDV/1/)

Comment: Quotes are not necessary, Sajad.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#flags {
position: relative;
background-image:url("example.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom right;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: No luck. Tried with and without quotes :(

Answer (score 0):

Try putting double quotes around image url like so

```
background-image:url("https://example.png");
```

Comment: Not necessary, unless there a special chars in the URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't set any dimensions for `#flags` div while your div element is floated. So you need to set either height and width of a `#flag` div or give a css property `overflow:hidden` to it's parent like given below. Then it will work perfectly fine.

**Code:**

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">

    <div id="flags">
        <p>text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>list1</li>
            <li>list2</li>
            <li>list3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Hopefully it will be your answer.

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ImLoa)

Comment: Will you please share your code with actual URL of an image?

Comment: is `example.png` the same image you want to show? What is the location of image and css file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your image address... It works when i put my own image in

```
    #flags {
    position: relative;
    background-image:url('http://th00.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/i/2012/193/2/9/agua_png_by_eross_666-d56zr6u.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
    float: right;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kq48W/1/

Comment: Tried 3 images and your link. Nothing at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that either your image path or extension is not correct. Check image extension and place the image in the same folder of html file.