# CSS 3 background not working

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get a background on a test website for a class.

```
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-image: url(Resorces/Background.png) repeat;}
```

This is from the CSS file
The HTML file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<title>Raster Vector Home</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use quotation marks like `url("Resorces/Background.png")`

Comment: First, you're missing quotations in the image path. Second, you can't have `repeat` in the `background-image` rule. It should look like this: `background-image: url("Resorces/Background.png");`. Also, please check if your path is correct relative to the .css file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.

1. You cannot have `repeat` in [background-image](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-image).
2. You should wrap the image url with single (`'`) or double quote (`"`) characters.

Instead, either create a separate attribute for [background-repeat](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-repeat)

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('Resorces/Background.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Or, just use the [background](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background) attribute:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url('Resorces/Background.png') repeat;
}
```

For more information on CSS background properties, see: [W3C: 14 Colors and Backgrounds](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html)

Comment: Just to be a bit pedantic. [The quotes are not required, with a minor caveat that certain characters need to be escaped](http://stackoverflow.com/a/851753/2930477).