# Jquery function html and escaping issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have string:

```
var items = "<div class='item'><div class='item-img' style='background-image: url('images.123.jpg')'></div></div>"
```

I want to change inner html of div:

```
$('#div').html(items);
```

So the result would be:

```
<div id="div">
    <div class='item'>
         <div class='item-img' style='background-image: url('images.123.jpg')'>  </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

How I can do that? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Cange it to `... style=\"background-image: url('images.123.jsp')\")>...` because if you use the same tick (') for `style=''` and `url ('')`, the first tick in url will close the tick from style=. The backslash in `\"` should quote the double quotes, so it doesn't close the quotes from you variable assignment.

Comment: @Alexander `.jsp` <> `.jpg`! hahaha

Comment: @mathielo typical typo for a Java Frontend developer ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var div = $('<div>').attr("id","div").html(items);
$("body").append(div);
```

Comment: and i get this `<div class="item-img" style="background-image: url(" images.123.jpg')'=""></div>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are breaking the attribute `style` with quotation marks right here:

```
[...] style='background-image: url('images.123.jpg')'> [...]
```

See? The *supposed-to-be* inner `'` actually breaks the `style=''` marks. As they [are not mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851753/2752041) for the CSS attribute, you could either not use them

```
var items = "<div class='item'><div class='item-img' style='background-image: url(images.123.jpg)'></div></div>"
```

OR you could escape double quotation marks:

```
var items = "<div class=\"item\"><div class=\"item-img\" style=\"background-image: url('images.123.jpg')\"></div></div>"
```