# Custom BG in CSS?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, Notepad++ isn't letting me import a picture for the bg of my website. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
body {
    background-image: url("C:\Users\3xpl\Desktop\HAK.net\images\background.png");
}
```

I really need help.
And a reminder: I'm on HTML5.

EDIT: Here's the full code: https://pastebin.com/MNEjc1p0

Comment: can you replace `*` with a valid directory ?

Comment: please read this, it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage

Comment: I did, I just blocked it out so u couldn't see my username lol

Comment: I don't understand. What does Notepad have to do with the background for your web site? And is this web site online? In which case that's another different path.

Comment: No, not online yet, and it's not notepad. It's notepad++ and I'm not sure that saving it as an HTML file includes CSS in the file extension with notepad++.

Answer (score -1):

Alright guys, fixed it. I had to find the raw imgres link to my bg. Thanks for the help anyway though.