# css how to use background-image

Tags: css, background-image

```
background-image: url(../images/title2);
```

im also trying to apply it to a container

i have a rootfolder called learning project inside it looks like this

[image: this is what it looks like inside]

My html page is inside html and my css is inside css both called index I'm trying to get from my css to my image folder to title2 which is just a random name and it wont work

Can anyone help?

Comment: Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet. You'll also need to reference the image's file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap the relative url in quotes
and thats it

```
background-image: url('../images/title2');
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was upvoted, as not only will it not work (due to the missing file extension), but [**quotation marks are entirely option**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851753/2341603).

Comment: @ObsidianAge only people without brain will not put extension after the file name. sry brother but if u r pro u must not look for small things no one has time to cry about small things

Comment: you didn't add extenstion, so you don't have brain?

Comment: @TemaniAfif earth is not flat by the way. lol. just chill brother thats for the sake of guidance and what i said was if someone doesn't use an exteniosn after havinng a look at this demo might not be havinng a brain

Comment: By the way, you can read the duplicate question to see that your answer is wrong ... like @ObsidianAge I don't know why it's getting upvoted.

Comment: just because earth is not flat