# I cannot seem to get background-image to render anything in css

Tags: html, css

I have been trying for the last 3 days to get background-image to work in css. I was able to get it to work in the past but I am not sure what is wrong now. At this point I copied a hero image example off of W3C and that didn't work either. I am trying to use background-image to add a header to my page. I do like the hero image idea so I'd like to stick with it.

The first set of code that I used was:

```css
header { background-image: url("banner.jpg"); }
```

```html
<header>
 <h1>Donald Goines</h1>
</header>
```

This rendered nothing as far as the picture goes. Donald Goines came up though. I also tried ../images/banner.jpg in the url because I realized that I did place this image in a folder within the original folder. I validated what I had and it came back with no errors.

```html
<body>
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Donald Goines</h1>
    <p>Author</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```css
.hero-image {

  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/banner.jpg");


  height: 50%;


  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Anything in dev tools (F12)? At a glance, what you have seems accurate enough so I'd check to make sure your banner is in the place the browser is looking for it.

Comment: I've tested it on my end and the image is displayed. Please share your folder structure and any other CSS code (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is essentially the code you started with, but with a minimum height of `50vh` instead of `50%` (`50%` of `0` is still `0`). The reason your `h1` content was displaying is that it takes up actual space in the DOM.

```css
.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516836554245-938416faa6ee?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80");
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Donald Goines</h1>
    <p>Author</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lr0ctn8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the parent of .hero-image has a height. I'm thinking your element may have no height (assuming the image's path is correct).

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder structure. That could be the reason the images are not pulling through. Without knowing the folder structure, it will be difficult to see if your CSS is correct. See this thread here.

[CSS background-image - What is the correct usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage)

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg");
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg");
  height: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Donald Goines</h1>
</header>

<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Donald Goines</h1>
    <p>Author</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be issue with path for the image. Try - background-image:url("images/banner.jpg");