# background-image is not loading even though the path is 100% correct

Tags: html, css

as a div background I want to load an image, in the css file for the backgroud-image property I give the path to the image, which is correct, but the image does not load,
but when somewhere, any place in html file, I use that code line

```
<img src="/static/images/map.png" class="map_photo" alt="map_photo">
```

then the background image for my div pops up and additionall, there is a picture loaded by this line of code above, it seems to me that this image is not pre-loaded, or something like that, so maybe i should add in my css file some code to allow load images to html

I'm useing the newest Intellij Ultimate, and I included all the necessary attachments below.

div into which I want to load the graphic is class **map**

```
  <section id="map_section">
    <div id="map"></div> <-- This DIV
    <div id="events"></div>
  </section>
```

My CSS code block

```
#map_section
{
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
}
#map {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    background-image: url(./images/map.png);
    background-position: center; /* Center the image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
    background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
}
```

And the image with project structure is added as a attachment [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7dhS.png)

Thx for Help!

Fast edit to make it clear
when my html code look like this:

```
  <img src="/static/images/map.png" class="map_photo" alt="map_photo">
  <section id="map_section">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="events"></div>
  </section>
```

i have situation like this: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LmJA.png)

when I delete  or comment that one line

```
<!--  <img src="/static/images/map.png" class="map_photo" alt="map_photo">-->
  <section id="map_section">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="events"></div>
  </section>
```

both images disappear: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGXcR.png)

Comment: What if you try to style this with inline CSS: `<div id="map" style="background-image: url('/static/images/map.png')">`?

Answer (score 0):

try butting your path in quotation marks .

`background-image: url('./images/map.png');`

Comment: theres no any difference

That line :
<img src="/static/images/map.png" class="map_photo" alt="map_photo">
is a problem or fixed, when I have it in my code background-image properties working well, when i delete it, background image is not loading.

Comment: didn't you try to give the background-image the same src as image .

Comment: if my background-image have same path as image srv 
`/static/images/map.png` 
there is no difference

with 
`<img src="/static/images/map.png" class="map_photo" alt="map_photo">`
is working well, but when i comment or delete that code line, its stopping works... maybe its intellij problem, but i dont think  so.

Comment: Quotes are optional. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage.

Comment: @NourMonir i made 2 more ss, pls czechk my post again, maybe it will be easier to understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

It is actually `../` not `./`.

So the correct code would be:

```
background-image: url(../images/map.png);
```

Comment: tryed it, no result, if u can pls check my post, i made edit at the end

Comment: @pkobylka Are you viewing this in IntelliJ's in-built preview? If so, try viewing the HTML in an actual browser. See if the code works correctly then.

Comment: I figure it out! My css file was linked incorrectly...
i had it like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css" type="text/css" />`
but when i changed it to this
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styles.css" type="text/css" />`
it started working correctly, I think i know answer, but can u ply try to explain me as simple and u can why it wasnt working well?

Comment: @pkobylka because the correct way is adding dot dot like ../ only putting the slash will not work.

Answer (score 0):

My css file was linked incorrectly... i had it like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css" type="text/css" />` but when i changed it to this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styles.css" type="text/css" />` it started working correctly.